# Error when moving Azure storage account to another resource group

Tags: azure-storage, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I wanted to move Azure storage account from one resource group to another (both in the same subscription). I issued command like this:

`Get-AzureResource -Name storage1 -ResourceGroupName RG-Test | Move-AzureResource -DestinationResourceGroupName Test01`

but got error:

`Move-AzureResource : {
  "Error": {
    "Code": "104",
    "Message": "Resources '/subscriptions/<guid>/resourceGroups/RG-Test/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storage1' could not be moved. The tracking Id is
'cf831a76-983d-4b0a-924f-437ad75fc5e3'",
    "Target": null,
    "Details": [
      {
        "Code": "0",
        "Message": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"HttpResourceNotFound\",\"message\":\"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
'https://globalxls.storage.azure.com:443/subscriptions/<guid>/resourceGroups/RG-Test/moveResources?api-version=2015-05-01-preview'.\"}}",
        "Target": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "Details": null
      }
    ]
  }
}`

The resource exists - I verified the first command returns the resource.
What can I do to move the storage account? The problem occurs for "Storage account" (with the green icon), not for "Storage account (classic)" with the blue icon in management portal.

Comment: I don't think storage accounts support the move api yet - let me verify and get back to you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, verified - storageAccounts don't support the move api just yet.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that moving resources between resource groups is yet only for subset of resources. Perhaps error saying "Not yet supported" would be better.. However, is there a list of which resources can be moved and which not yet somewhere?

Comment: A lot of the errors can be improved as you noted... we're working on that.  In the meantime, you can see the latest list here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-move-resources/